# Gensim saved dictionary has no id2token

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I have saved a Gensim dictionary to disk. When I load it, the `id2token` attribute dict is not populated.

A simple piece of the code that saves the dictionary:

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(tag_docs)
dictionary.save("tag_dictionary_lda.pkl")
```

Now when I load it (I'm loading it in an jupyter notebook), it still works fine for mapping tokens to IDs, but `id2token` does not work (I cannot map IDs to tokens) and in fact `id2token` is not populated at all.

```
> dictionary = corpora.Dictionary.load("../data/tag_dictionary_lda.pkl")
> dictionary.token2id["love"]
Out: 1613

> dictionary.doc2bow(["love"])
Out: [(1613, 1)]

> dictionary.id2token[1613]
Out: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input> in <module>()
----> 1 dictionary.id2token[1613]

KeyError: 1613

> list(dictionary.id2token.keys())
Out: []
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You don't need the `dictionary.id2token[1613]` as you can use `dictionary[1613]` directly.

Note, that if you check the `dictionary.id2token` afterwards, it won't be empty any more. That's because the `dictionary.id2token` is formed only on request to save memory (as is stated during the init of Dictionary class).

Comment: Thank you, this works. I had difficulty finding `id2token` in the documentation. Maybe I should submit a pull request to gensim to add docs explaining this.

Comment: Do you know what the intended purpose of ``id2token[ix]`` is? If it's not guaranteed to return the expected token, and ``dictionary[ix]`` works just as good I mean.

Comment: I suppose there is some purpose behind this, but I don't have a clue. You may try to ask somebody from gensim team directly.